# CPU and RAM MHz Riddle

Tags: memory, cpu

A few days ago I bought a whole PC which will be delivered tomorrow. I choose:

- Intel Core i7-2600K 3.4GHz 8M cache LGA 1155
- 8GB DDR3 1600 CL9 Corsair XMS

I hadn't checked that the CPU needs 1333MHz RAM and now I'm stuck.

Will the BIOS set the RAM to 1333MHz and everything will work without any problems, or should I avoid starting up the PC?

Comment: When you say "I bought [a] whole PC" do you mean that it is all assembled? Or is it a DIY system? Do you know the specs of the motherboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CPU is compatible with the memory, the question is, is the motherboard compatible with it.

it is highly likely that the memory will simply underclock to a more conventional speed such as 1333Mhz.

There are chances it won't work, but, I honestly can't say - every motherboard is different.

Answer (score 0):

The system *should* work at the 1333 RAM speed of the CPU. That said, anything involving electricity has an inherent risk associated with it and the whole thing could catch on fire when you turn it on.

But more than likely everything will be just fine.

Comment: Thanks for reply.

Motherboard is ASUS Sabertooth P67 revision3.0 and it's compatibly with RAM
http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1155/SABERTOOTH_P67/#specifications

But about CPU you are wrong. It's working with 1066 and 1333 only (http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=52214)

Comment: @Ivp the mention of fire was purely a worst case consideration. Computer components are usually pretty good at sacrificing themselves before a short circuit would build to the point of causing something like a fire.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of feedback for your motherboard on [Newegg.com](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=13-131-702&SortField=0&SummaryType=0&Pagesize=10&PurchaseMark=&SelectedRating=-1&VideoOnlyMark=False&VendorMark=&IsFeedbackTab=true&Page=9#scrollFullInfo), and one user has experienced problems with 1600MHz memory modules. But it was resolved by enabling XMP in the motherboard bios. So i would try that if the system does not work right away.

Comment: Thanks Sharken! I didn't knew this site but as I see there are many great tips and reviews!